# Make div move other divs on hover

Tags: html, css

I want my "appear"-div to appear when my "box"-div is hover.  the other "box"-divs should stay where they are, unless the divs under. So if i hover one of the 4 "box"-divs in the top, the 8 other divs should move down, so there is space for the red bow.

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div class="beholder">
    <div class="beholder_lille">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="appear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beholder_lille">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="appear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beholder_lille">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="appear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beholder_lille">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="appear"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="beholder">
    <div class="beholder_lille">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="appear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beholder_lille">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="appear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beholder_lille">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="appear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beholder_lille">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="appear"></div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.beholder {
width: 50%;
display:table;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.beholder_lille {
background-color: green;
float: left;
margin:0 4%;
margin-bottom: 30%;
}


.box , .appear{
 background: blue;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px; 
 float:left;
}


.appear{
background:red;
float: left;
display: none;
clear: both;
height: 600px;
width: 600px;
}
.box:hover{
 background: #e6e6e6;

}

 .box:hover + .appear {
 display:block;  
}
```

Really hope some mastermind can help me

Comment: You can use jQuery or javascript for it

Comment: Do you have to keep your HTML structure?

Comment: How? am i supposed to put jQuery in the html or css? @C0dekid

Comment: It has to be 4 divs in a row @exoslav

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you're trying to achieve on hover?

Comment: I can roughly picture what you're trying to explain, but could you give an image or something? This is still too vague a question, not without at least a sketch or something to figure out what goes on in your head.

Comment: Your problem I think would be pushing everything down and making the "appear" box work properly. Question is, where are you intending to have that box?

Comment: any way i can attach an image? @ovokuro

Comment: I made a fiddle, maybe that code is sufficient for you: https://jsfiddle.net/zdmtp7rs/

Comment: @Mark I have a small image in the "box" div and it has to appear much bigger when you hover.

Comment: @exoslav Yes exacly. The other divs should move down under, unless the divs that is in the same row as the div that you hover

Comment: Try imgur.com, it's free and takes no time at all, then edit your post and insert the link somewhere visible, or hyperlink it to a word or something

Comment: @Mark a jsfiddle has been made in the comments

Comment: I am afraid you have to do it by javascript, can you use it in your project?

Comment: yes, but i am clueless when it comes to Javascript @exoslav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made a fiddle using javascript (jQuery). Everytime you hover on `.box` element, it counts height difference between `.beholder` and `.appear` and set this difference as `margin-bottom` to `.beholder`. If height difference is less than zero, it returns from a function. You can adjust your bottom margin in `var adjust` I set it to 20...

https://jsfiddle.net/zdmtp7rs/5/

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Is it possible that the redbox moves the divs under it, insted of just overlapping them? And where should i insert javascript?

Comment: I tohught that the divs in the same rows remains in their position: "The other divs should move down under, unless the divs that is in the same row as the div that you hover"

Comment: Conserning jQuery, put this one (`<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`) into your `<head>` tag

Comment: And you can copy JS code from fiddle and put it into `<script type="text/javascript">your code</script>` tags just before your ending body tag: `</body>`. Or find some tutorial on the internet, its really easy.

Comment: But i still cant figure out how to make some of the divs stay in their position. The divs in the same row has to stay where they are, and the rest has to moke down. Any clue how?

Comment: I am not sure what behaviour zou want to achieve. For example, current fiddle works like: when I hover the very first div, red square block cover the rest of the divs on the right side, but divs in second `.beholder` move down. You want to move down all divs, that are covered by red square, as well?

Comment: they jsfiddle just dosnt behave the way it does in the demo, when i insert it in dreamweaver. TNone of the divs moves down. But your jsfiddle is the result im looking for, but the green div has to be hidden.

Comment: Try to wrap the JS code to `$(document).ready(function() { JS code from jsfiddle })`, see here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I do not have a "<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>". What am i supposed to link to

Comment: Follow these steps:
1. add the jQuery library to your `<head/>` tag (its in third comment):
`<head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js..."
</head>`
2. just before `</body>` tag , add the JS code for div handeling:
`<script>$(document).ready(function() { code from jsfiddle })</script>`

Or find on the internet how to add javascript to your page. I updated the fiddle to have `$(document).ready(function() {})` function: https://jsfiddle.net/zdmtp7rs/6/

Comment: man thank you very much, really need your help! Any way the greem box can disappear when i hover?

Comment: yeah exacly. Cause when i have javascript, editing my css wont do anything. Can i move the red box so it appears the same place no matter where i hover?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138843/discussion-between-exoslav-and-adrian-kirkegaard).